# How to get current Login User Name from sharepoint in SSRS report instead of the SSRS report user name show the serviceAccount name

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, reporting-services

Currently when run SSRS in development, the user name is show correctly. But, once deploy it to sharepoint, the user name become static which means it keep display service Account name and not the current sharepoint login user name.

Anyone know how to make the SSRS reporting display the current sharepoint login user name instead of display service account name?

Many thanks.

Regards,
Lilian

Answer (score 0):

use the CurrentUser Webpart filter.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.